# Google Cloud Pub/Sub triggers high latency on low messages throughput

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

i'm running project which publishes messages to a PubSub topic and triggers background cloud function.

I read that with high volumes of messages, it performs well, but for lesser amounts like hundreds or even tens of messages per second, Pub/Sub may yield high latencies..

Code example to publish single message:

```js
 const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

 const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

 async function publishMessage() {
    const topicName = 'my-topic';
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

    const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer);
    console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
 }

 publishMessage().catch(console.error);
```

Code example function triggered by PubSub:

```js
exports.subscribe = async (message) => {
  const name = message.data
    ? Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';

  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
}
```

Cloud Function Environment Details: 
Node: 8 
google-cloud/pubsub: 1.6.0

The problem is when using PubSub with low throughput of messages (for example, 1 request per second) it struggles sometimes and shows incredibly high latency (up to **7-9s** or more).

Is there a way or workaround to make PubSub perform well each time (**50ms** or less delay) even with small amount of incoming messages?

Comment: Are you speculating or do you have an actual problem with specific details?

Comment: @JohnHanley, no, it's actual problem. Which details do you need?

Comment: I do not see a problem in your question - just an assumption that Pub/Sub is slow. Provide details on what your problem is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnHanley edited

Comment: When you say "latency" do you mean publish latency or end-to-end latency?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn I mean publish latency

Answer (score 2):

If you are always publishing to the same topic, you'd be better off keeping the object returned from `pubSubClient.topic(topicName)` and reusing it, whether you have a small number or large number of messages. If you want to minimize latency, you'll also want to set the `maxMilliseconds` property of the `batching` setting. By default, this is 10ms. As you have the code now, it means that every publish waits 10ms to send a message in hopes of filling the batch. Given that you create a new publisher via the `topic` call on every publish, you are guaranteed to always wait at least 10ms. You can set it when you call `topic`:

```
const publisher = pubSubClient.topic(topicName, {
      batching: {
        maxMessages: 100,
        maxMilliseconds: 1,
      },
    });
```

If after reusing the the object returned from `pubSubClient.topic(topicName)` and changing `maxMilliseconds` you are still experiencing such a delay, then you should reach out to [Google Cloud Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) so they can look at the specific project and topic you are using as that kind of latency is definitely not expected.

Comment: Hi, i found out that in Metrics (GC Monitoring) i can see messages are delayed for some reason when i see  "unreachable_5xx_error_500", i cannot find anything on web about this

Comment: For which metric?

Comment: resource - Google Pub/Sub Subscription, metric - Push Latency.
Here is screenshot of chart:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqTqM.png